# php накопить массив данными в цикле

Tags: php, массивы

как в массив который в цикле записать данные по условию?
Нужно в массив $array записать данные, которые НЕ равны 'good'

```
$rules = [
    'name' => [$rr1],
    'description' => [$arr2],
    'text' => [$arr3]
];
foreach ($rules as $rule => $i) {
    if ($validation->validate_field($rules[$rule]) == 'good') {
        $answer[] = 'good';
    } else {
        $answer[] = 'error';
        $array = [ //в этот массив записать все данные которые не равны строчке 'good'
            $rule => $rules[$rule]
        ]; 
    }
}

return $array;
```

результат:

Возвращается только одна запись

Как в массив $array записать все данные которые соответствуют условию?

**Решение:**

нужно перезаписать массив

```
$array2 = [
    $rule => $rules[$rule],
];
$array[] = $array2;
```

Comment: `$array[] = $i;` будет записывать все item'ы с error'ами. Или то что уже есть, только так -> `$array[] = [ $rule =>$rules[$rule]  ]; `

Comment: @InDevX, все равно одна запись возвращается

Comment: У вас сначала написано записать те, что равны good, ниже в комментарии к коду записать все, которые не равны good

Comment: @Kirill, ошибся при редактировании страницы, нужно которые НЕ равны 'good'

Comment: $array[$rule] = $i; Вместо $array = [ $rule => $rules[$rule]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($rules as $rule => $i) {
   ...
} else {
    ...
    $array[$rule] = $i;
    ]; 
}
```